# Rank of Cartesian product of well-partial-orders

Tags: reference-request, ordinal-numbers

We are interested in the ordinal rank $h(P)$ of a wpo (a well-partial-order). It is known that it coincides with the order type of its longest chain.

When we consider the cartesian product $P\times Q$, where couples are ordered component-wise, we end up with the following:

$h(P\times Q)=1+\sup\{\alpha\oplus\beta~|~\alpha<h(P)\land\beta<h(Q)\}$

This is a bit different from $h(P)\oplus h(Q)$ but it is still "natural".

Is there any work where this operation on ordinals already appears?
And has anyone already computed the ordinal rank of cartesian products?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ordinal rank of cartesian products has already been computed. See Lemma 1.9 in U. Abraham and R. Bonnet, *Hausdorff's theorem for posets that satisfy the finite antichain property*, Fund. Math. 159 (1999), 1:51-69. [MR1669718](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1669718).

Thanks to R. Bonnet who provided the ref (and more information) in private email.